# How to query data base on whether the condition exists in mysql?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to query my table with different condition, but it depends on the client side input, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE f_username like 'frank' and f_country = "%UK%".
```

Since I wrote my server in Python, so my query will be:

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE f_username like '%s' and f_country = "%%s%"."""
cur.execute(sql, ('frank', 'UK'))
```

But, sometime, the user don't want to filter by country, so they might only get the `keyword`. so my query should be like:

```
SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE f_username like 'frank'
```

Also, my python will be like:

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE f_username like '%s'"""
    cur.execute(sql, ('frank',))
```

and then, I can check the params, decide which `sql` I should use it, but In my actual project, it has many filter require, that would may me build many many condition check, something like:

```
if not country_id and not city_id and not keyword:
    condition = """
        WHERE f_username=%s
    """
elif country_id and not city_id and not keyword:
    condition = """
        WHERE f_username=%s and f_country=%s
    """
elif not country_id and city_id and not keyword:
    condition = """
        WHERE f_username=%s and f_city=%s
    """
elif not country_id and not city_id and keyword:
    condition = """
        WHERE f_username=%s and f_activity_title like (%%s%)
    """
elif country_id and city_id and not keyword:
    condition = """
        WHERE f_username=%s and f_country=%s and f_city=%s
```

Anyway, it works. but I want it more Pythonic, like :

```
WHERE f_username=(%s or '*')  and f_country=(%s or '*' and f_city=(%s or '*)
```

I know it not really correct sql syntax, but can you help me find a good one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Stored Procedure.**

Below is a MySQL procedure example:

**(Update):**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE country_hos
(IN country CHAR(50))
(IN Info CHAR(50))
begin
   select * from t where
   (country=@country OR @country is null) and
   (info like '%'+@info+'%') -- if info is not provided and @info is empty then an empty string will return all the data.
End
```

**SQL Server procedure example:**

```
create proc sp_someCatchyName
@country varchar(50),
@Info varchar(50)
as
begin
   select * from t where
   (country=@country OR @country is null) and
   (info like '%'+@info+'%') -- if info is not provided and @info is empty then an empty string will return all the data.
end
```

However, if you are planning to do the inline SQL in python as per the conversation in the SQL chatroom, after some searches about python code (i don't know python though) following code should give you the direction of work via which you can achieve your goal:

**inline python sql code example:**

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE f_username like '%s' and (f_country = "%%s%" OR %s is null)."""

cur.execute(sql, ('frank', 'UK')) //when both params given
cur.execute(sql, ('frank', null)) //when country is not given
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE f_username like '%s%' and f_country like = "%s%"."""
```

link > [1]: http://2015.padjo.org/tutorials/sql-basics/fuzzy-matching-like-in-where/

Answer (score 0):

It's best to separate the parameters from the sql if you can. Then you can let the db module take care of proper quoting of the parameters.

```
sql="""SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE f_username like '%s'."""
args=[beginningOfString+'%']
cursor.execute(sql,args)
```